# Image not loading in React when I import the url from another file

Tags: reactjs

Images are not loading when i try to get it form imported data.
Here is the code

```
import React from 'react'
import data from '../../data' 


export default function Destination() {

  const { name , images, description, distance, travel } = data.destinations[0];
  console.log(images.png)

  return (
    <section className='destination-container'>
      <h2 className='sub-heading'> <span className='num'> 01 </span>  Pick Your Destination </h2>
      <article className='destination-info'>
        <div className='destination-img'>
          <img src= { images.png } />
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Here is the data that is imported

```
"destinations": [
    {
      "name": "Moon",
      "images": {
        "png": "../../assets/destination/image-moon.png",
        "webp": "../../assets/destination/image-moon.webp"
      },
      "description": "See our planet as you’ve never seen it before. A perfect relaxing trip away to help regain perspective and come back refreshed. While you’re there, take in some history by visiting the Luna 2 and Apollo 11 landing sites.",
      "distance": "384,400 km",
      "travel": "3 days"
    },
]
```

But when import it directly it works

```
import img from '../../assets/destination/image-moon.png'
```

Here is my folder structure
[image]

Comment: If you are following mentioned approach then it's looking into `public` folder i.e. looking for mentioned URL from base address but when you import it explicitly then it's imported properly as image component for react.

Comment: So, I need to get into src folder first and then search for the image in data file ?

Comment: Can you tell me what path should i put in the data.js file for the image.